# Sampling frequency error in OFDM

Tags: sampling, ofdm

If the sampling rates at receiver and at transmitter are different, there will be ICI.

However I don't find any practical technique to estimate and compensate this kind of error. Is it true that we always assume that error is small and ignore it?

What would the constellation look like if we have sampling rate error?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OFDM sampling frequency offset](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70537/ofdm-sampling-frequency-offset)

Comment: @MarcusMüller not really. There is something I don't agree with your answer. Will post my question in the comment section. Sorry your link did not pop up when I posted my question. You can either close or delete this question. Thank you.

Comment: Anna, that's OK! Especially if my answers answers something else than you were interested to ask, you should edit your question to specify what that is (and how specifically the existing answers fail to address it).